# R - Adding Data Frame to Matrix

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-transform

I am trying to transform a data frame (treating as a vector) with locational data and a value onto a matrix that uses locational data as it's row and column names.

(Run snippets to see layout examples.)

Example of the vector:

```html
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>"Longitude"</th>
    <th>"Latitude"</th>
    <th>"Value"</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>65</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Example of the matrix:

```html
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <td>0.00</td>
    <td>0.00</td>
    <td>0.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2</th>
    <td>0.00</td>
    <td>0.00</td>
    <td>0.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>3</th>
    <td>0.00</td>
    <td>0.00</td>
    <td>0.00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The result I want is:

```html
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <td>0.00</td>
    <td>65.00</td>
    <td>0.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2</th>
    <td>10.00</td>
    <td>0.00</td>
    <td>0.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>3</th>
    <td>0.00</td>
    <td>0.00</td>
    <td>100.00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Essentially, I want to treat the data frame as a series of vectors and transform them onto the matrix but my past attempts have resulted in the matrix transforming itself into a list instead.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try `xtabs(Value ~ Latitutde + Longitude, data = df1)`

Comment: Arghh. This is not the purpose of code snippets. Just copy your input as text and use the code markup.

Comment: Even better would be to use `dput` to paste your data in a format we could work with.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this easily with `xtabs` from `base R`

```
out <- xtabs(Value ~ Latitude + Longitude, df1)
names(dimnames(out)) <- NULL
out
#    1   2   3
#1   0  65   0
#2  10   0   0
#3   0   0 100
```